# Python: Script doesn't run without print

Tags: python-2.7, qt4, pyqt4

I have written a small executable script. This program only works when I use a `print`-statement (at the end of the `on_start()`-method of the `QDialog()`class). Please, take a look in the `on_start()`-method of the `QDialog`-class.

As you can see I create an a `task_thread`- and `work_object`-instance. But, when I execute this script without `print`-statement nothing happens - no Traceback or other error messages.

Where is the bug? I guess the problem is that I create the instances at the local level - I am not sure. How can I fix it?

```
import sys
from time import sleep

from PyQt4.QtCore import QThread, pyqtSignal, Qt, QStringList, QObject, QTimer
from PyQt4.QtGui import QVBoxLayout, QPushButton, QDialog, QProgressBar, QApplication, \
     QMessageBox, QTreeWidget, QTreeWidgetItem, QLabel

def create_items(total):
     for elem in range(total):
         yield elem

class WorkObject(QObject):

    notify_progress = pyqtSignal(object)
    fire_label = pyqtSignal(object)
    finished = pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QObject.__init__(self, parent)

    def add_items(self):
         total = 190000

         x = (total/100*1)
         a = x

         counter = 0

         for element in create_items(10000):
              counter += 1
              self.notify_progress.emit((element))
              self.fire_label.emit((counter))

              if counter == x:
                   x += a
                   sleep(1)

              if not self.keep_running:
                   self.keep_running = True
                   break

    def run(self):
         self.keep_running = True
         self.add_items()

    def stop(self):
         self.keep_running = False


class MyCustomDialog(QDialog):

    finish = pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QDialog.__init__(self, parent)

        layout = QVBoxLayout(self)

        self.tree = QTreeWidget(self)
        self.label = QLabel(self)

        self.pushButton_start = QPushButton("Start", self)
        self.pushButton_stopp = QPushButton("Stopp", self)
        self.pushButton_close = QPushButton("Close", self)

        layout.addWidget(self.label)
        layout.addWidget(self.tree)
        layout.addWidget(self.pushButton_start)
        layout.addWidget(self.pushButton_stopp)
        layout.addWidget(self.pushButton_close)

        self.pushButton_start.clicked.connect(self.on_start)
        self.pushButton_stopp.clicked.connect(self.on_finish)
        self.pushButton_close.clicked.connect(self.close)

    def fill_tree_widget(self, i):
        parent = QTreeWidgetItem(self.tree)
        self.tree.addTopLevelItem(parent)
        parent.setText(0, unicode(i))
        parent.setCheckState(0, Qt.Unchecked)
        parent.setFlags(parent.flags() | Qt.ItemIsTristate | Qt.ItemIsUserCheckable)

    def on_label(self, i):
         self.label.setText("Result: {}".format(i))

    def on_start(self):
         self.tree.clear()
         self.label.clear()

         task_thread = QThread(self)
         work_object = WorkObject()

         work_object.fire_label.connect(self.on_label)
         work_object.notify_progress.connect(self.fill_tree_widget)
         work_object.finished.connect(task_thread.quit)

         self.finish.connect(work_object.stop)

         work_object.moveToThread(task_thread)

         task_thread.started.connect(work_object.run)

         task_thread.finished.connect(task_thread.deleteLater)

         timer = QTimer()

         # I set the single shot timer on False,
         # because I don't want the timer to fires only once,
         # it should fires every interval milliseconds
         timer.setSingleShot(False)
         timer.timeout.connect(work_object.stop)
         timer.start(0)

         task_thread.start()

         print

    def on_finish(self):
         self.finish.emit()

def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MyCustomDialog()
    window.resize(600, 400)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

You are right, `work_object` is created as a local instance.

Here is a simple solution:

```
work_object = WorkObject()
self.work_object = work_object  # Add this line
```